# graphs where every cycle is a sum of triangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, triangles, cycles

I am studying a special kind of graphs, and I would like to know if they are studied in the literature and what they are called.
Let $G$ be a simple, finite, undirected, connected graph, with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$.
Consider the $\mathbb R$-vector space that is generated by all pairs $(x,y)\in V^2$ with $\{x,y\}\in E$, using the convention that $(x,y) = -(y,x)$.
This vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[E]$, choosing a direction for each edge.
To each cycle $C = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in the graph we associate the element $(x_1,x_2)+(x_2,x_3)+\ldots+(x_{n-1},x_n)+(x_n,x_1)$ in this vector space.
The subspace generated by all cycles is denoted $Z(G)$.
It is characterized by the equality $\sum_{y\sim x}c((x,y)) = 0$ for all $c\in Z(G)$ and $x\in V$.

In particular, to any triangle $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in the graph we associate the cycle $(x_1,x_2)+(x_2,x_3)+(x_3,x_1)$.
The vector space generated by all triangles is denoted $Z_3(G) \subseteq Z(G)$.
The graphs I am interested in are the graphs for which $Z_3(G) = Z(G)$.
Equivalently, there should be $|E|-|V|+1$ linearly independent triangles.
A direct consequence is that every edge that is an cycle is also in a triangle.
Examples of these graphs are triangular grids and wheel graphs. Every chordal graph satisfies $Z_3(G) = Z(G)$ but the opposite is not true.

**Is this kind of graph studied in the literature and what is it called?**

Comment: basically you are considering simplicial complexes of vertices, edges, and triangles of graphs. A complex is called simply connected if its fundamental group F is trivial. Your condition says that F is perfect, i.e. its abelianisation is trivial.

Comment: What's an example of a graph that satisfies the condition but isn't chordal?

Comment: A wheel graph is not chordal.

Comment: Do connected graphs whose clique complexes are simply connected satisfy the condition?

Comment: I think so yes.